Repeated integral of $\tan x$
I searched the internet for a formula of the repeated integral of $\tan$ and found nothing so I am now interested in this problem, after trying in wolframalpha, it seems that the formula contains imaginary numbers and polylogarithm function, I am wondering if I should look in this form
$$\int_{0}^{x_{n}}\int_{0}^{x_{n-1}}\cdots\int_{0}^{x}\tan x \,dx\cdots\,dx_{n-1}$$
Or generally in this form
$$\int\cdots\int\tan x$$
Are the two forms equal?
Also in the second form I encountered the problem of finding the integral $$\int\ln(1+e^{2ix})$$
So it seems that the second option is not a better idea, what do you think guys ?

Wolfram Functions gives two solutions. You can find the first one using the Taylor series expansion of $\tan(x)$ around $x=0$ and the second one via the representation in terms of polygamma functions.

You can use Cauchy's formula for repeated integration to reduce the evaluation to a single definite integral:
$$f_n(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\int_0^{x_{1}}\cdots\int_{0}^{x_{n-1}}\tan x_n\, dx_n dx_{n-1}\cdots dx_2 dx_1$$
$$\qquad=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^x(x-t)^{n-1}\tan t\,dt.$$
The result is of the form
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{p=0}^n a_{n,p}x^p+b_n\text{Li}_n(-e^{2ix}),\;\;0<x<\pi/2.$$
Reconstruction of the coefficients:
$$a_{n,n}=\frac{i}{n!},\;\;a_{n,n-1}=\frac{\ln 2}{(n-1)!},\;\;b_n=\frac{1}{(2i)^{n-1}},$$
$$a_{n,p}=-c_{n,p}i^{p}\zeta(n-p),\;\;c_{n,p}\in\mathbb{Q}>0,\;\;p=0,1,\ldots n-2.$$

If we adopt the second form and using the series of polylogarithm function, we find that:
$$
\begin{split}
\int \tan x \,dx & =-\ln⁡(\cos x)+C_{0} \\
&=\ln⁡(2)+ix+\mathrm{Li}_{1}(-e^{2ix})+C_{0}\\
\int\int \tan x \,dx\,dx  & = \ln⁡(2)x+i \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2i} \mathrm{Li}_{2}(-e^{2ix})+C_{1}\\
\int\int\int \tan x \,dx\,dx\,dx  & = \ln⁡(2)\frac{x^2}{2}+i \frac{x^3}{3!} - \frac{1}{4} \mathrm{Li}_{3}(-e^{2ix})+C_{2}\\
\int\int\int\int \tan x \,dx\,dx\,dx\,dx  & = \ln⁡(2)\frac{x^3}{3!}+i \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{1}{8i} \mathrm{Li}_{4}(-e^{2ix})+C_{3}\\
\int\int\int\int\int \tan x \,dx\,dx\,dx\,dx\,dx  & = \ln⁡(2)\frac{x^4}{4!}+i \frac{x^5}{5!} + \frac{1}{16} \mathrm{Li}_{5}(-e^{2ix})+C_{4}\\
\end{split}
$$
So we can say that:
$$\int\cdots\int \tan x \underbrace{\,dx\cdots\,dx}_\text{n} = \ln⁡(2)\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+i \frac{x^n}{n!} + \frac{1}{2^{n}i^{n-1}} \mathrm{Li}_{n}(-e^{2ix})+C_{n-1}$$
where $C_{n-1}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$.
we can prove that by induction, we have:
$$
\begin{split}
\int\cdots\int \tan x \underbrace{\,dx\cdots\,dx}_\text{n+1} & = \ln⁡(2)\int\ \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+i \int\ \frac{x^n}{n!} + \frac{1}{2^{n}i^{n-1}} \int\ \mathrm{Li}_{n}(-e^{2ix})+\int\ C \\
&=\frac{\ln⁡(2)}{(n-1)!}\left(\frac{x^n}{n}+A\right)+\frac{i}{n!}\left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+B\right)+\frac{1}{2^{n}i^{n-1}} \int\ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-e^{2ix})^{k}}{k^{n}} \\
&=\ln⁡(2)\frac{x^n}{n!}+i\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{2^{n}i^{n-1}}  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k^{n}}\int\ e^{2ikx}+E \\
&=\ln⁡(2)\frac{x^n}{n!}+i\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{2^{n}i^{n-1}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k^{n}}\left(\frac{e^{2ikx}}{2ik}+E\right)+D \\
&=\ln⁡(2)\frac{x^n}{n!}+i\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{2^{n}i^{n-1}}\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-e^{2ix})^{k}}{k^{n+1}}+F \\
&=\ln⁡(2)\frac{x^n}{n!}+i\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}i^{n}}\mathrm{Li}_{n+1}(-e^{2ix})+F
\end{split}
$$

in your final equation, the coefficient in front of  $\operatorname{Li}_{n+1}$ should be $(2i)^{-n}$, rather than $1/(2^{n+1}i^n)$ -- at least, that is what I find.

just check $\int \tan dx$ , it has a term $\operatorname{Li}_1(-e^{2ix})$ not $\tfrac{1}{2}\operatorname{Li}_1(-e^{2ix})$
